# How reimport .targets file in Visual Studio?

Tags: msbuild

I work in Visual Studio. It seems for me, that, if I change anything in imported .targets file, the new version of .targets is not reimported to main project while building it. If I reopen my project (I.e. close and open again Visual Studio) and then launch build - the new version of .targets works.

Is it possible to tell Visual Studio to import .targets at any rebuild?

I tried use "rebuild" and "clean" solution and project, without any result regarding the problem.

Comment: If the rebuild can't work, then what about clean solution, then unload and reload the project file.

Comment: Lance Li-MSFT, no, this doesn't provide any effect either, but thanks for suggestion, I didn't try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-evaluating imported files is done by the new CPS-based project systems that are used for .NET Core / .NET Standard projects.

For VS versions before VS 2019, you may also need to indicate to MSBuild that the imported targets file should also re-trigger incremental build by adding its path to `$(MSBuildAllProjects)` (this is no longer needed in MSBuild 16 / VS 2019):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MSBuildAllProjects>$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)</MSBuildAllProjects>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But for "classic" .NET Framework / ASP.NET projects, you still need to close and re-open the solution for changes to take effect inside the IDE.

Also see [this GitHub tracking issue for the legacy project system](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2888).

Comment: Martin Ullrich, please could you say, where I should place this construction:
<PropertyGroup>
  <MSBuildAllProjects>$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)</MSBuildAllProjects>
</PropertyGroup>?

I added it to imported .target and importing project, but didn't see the change in the behavior of VS regarding the problem.

Comment: It's supposed to go into the imported targets file, but it only helps with incremental compilation in some parts of the build (e.g. publish) but may not take effect for the "design-time" builds of the legacy project system.